# Finding a string inside an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, search

I need to find an inner text of an element inside an XmlDocument and return it's Xpath.
for example, searching for "*ThisText*" inside :

```
<xml>
<xml2>ThisText</xml2>
</xml>
```

should return the Xpath of xml2

what's the most efficient way of doing this in c#?

Comment: If you can provide a bit more detail of your actual "input" and your desired "output" then might be able to help further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think the "xpath" of an element is? An xpath is a querying language in order to find a node/nodes, not to describe where a node is.

You can use an xpath to find the element in question. e.g.

```
xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), 'ThisText')]");
```

Then you can loop through the returned nodes and look at their name / parent, etc.